# Why does query __isnull=True cause DatabaseError?

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel

When I do a filter on a ForeignKey field with `__isnull=True`, this exception is raised:

```
DatabaseError: This query is not supported by the database.
```

However, `__isnull=False` on ForeignKey works as long as there are no other inequality filters (which I would expect). And `__isnull=True` works for other field types.

So why does `__isnull=True` not work on ForeignKey? It seems that `DBIndexer` tries to make it work as shown here:
https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-dbindexer/blob/dbindexer-1.4/dbindexer/backends.py

But then there is an exception in djangotoolbox:

```
  File "/Users//Documents/workspace/-gae-dev/src/django/db/models/query.py", line 107, in _result_iter
    self._fill_cache()
  File "/Users//Documents/workspace/-gae-dev/src/django/db/models/query.py", line 774, in _fill_cache
    self._result_cache.append(self._iter.next())
  File "/Users//Documents/workspace/-gae-dev/src/django/db/models/query.py", line 275, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/Users//Documents/workspace/-gae-dev/src/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py", line 337, in results_iter
    results = self.build_query(fields).fetch(
  File "/Users//Documents/workspace/-gae-dev/src/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py", line 428, in build_query
    self.check_query()
  File "/Users//Documents/workspace/-gae-dev/src/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py", line 409, in check_query
    raise DatabaseError("This query is not supported by the database.")
```

I did come across the following commented-out test case in djangoappengine, and am wondering if is referring to the same issue?

```
    def test_is_null(self):
        self.assertEquals(FieldsWithOptionsModel.objects.filter(
            floating_point__isnull=True).count(), 0)

        FieldsWithOptionsModel(
            integer=5.4, email='shinra.tensai@sixpaths.com',
            time=datetime.datetime.now().time()).save()

        self.assertEquals(FieldsWithOptionsModel.objects.filter(
            floating_point__isnull=True).count(), 1)

        # XXX: These filters will not work because of a Django bug.
#        self.assertEquals(FieldsWithOptionsModel.objects.filter(
#            foreign_key=None).count(), 1)

        # (it uses left outer joins if checked against isnull)
#        self.assertEquals(FieldsWithOptionsModel.objects.filter(
#            foreign_key__isnull=True).count(), 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex Burgel on the NonRel project set me straight:

The NonRel/dbindexer project fixes this query (which otherwise doesn't work due to this Django bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10790). To set up dbindexer:

- of course, add it to INSTALLED_APPS
- also in settings.py, set DATABASES['default]['ENGINE']= 'dbindexer'
- also in settings.py, set DBINDEXER_BACKENDS to use FKNullFix. For example:

DBINDEXER_BACKENDS = (
    'dbindexer.backends.BaseResolver',
    'dbindexer.backends.FKNullFix',
    'dbindexer.backends.InMemoryJOINResolver',
    'dbindexer.backends.ConstantFieldJOINResolver',
)